# SQL Error on lead form for email - CRM 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2015

On the lead form when I enter in Email id and hit save it throws a following SQL error below, but there's no error, if I leave it empty.

[image: error message]

here is the log file message

> **Unhandled Exception:**
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault,
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Generic SQL error.Detail:

Based on the log file message and the public key token and research, I disabled the plugin activity plugin on lead form, I still receive  the error message on form.

How to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to debug the Generic SQL Error message to find more detail on the problem. Try turning on server logging and review the CRM log files, failing that try and capture the error within SQL.